# Accuracy of directions using Long/Lat with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im using the Google Maps API v3 to show directions from a user defined starting point to my property.

This is technically working ok except for the accuracy of the end point. I have defined the Long/Lat of my property to the exact point but the directions still take you to a street about 100 metres away.

Is there a way to force the directions to take you to an exact point?

Here's my code in case it helps...

```
function getDirections(x, y) {

            $("#directionsPanel").html("");
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                scrollwheel: false
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

            var request = {
                origin: x,
                destination: $('.lat').text() + ',' + $('.lng').text() ,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                region: "GB"
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {

                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    $(".noValidRoute").hide();

            });

        }
```

Comment: Your `travelMode` is DRIVING.

Comment: Yes, but why do the directions stop a few hundred yards further up the road or even on a nearby road?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `x,y` in `getDirections(x, y)` are the coordinates of your property you are only using `x`.

TRY
;

```
function getDirections(x, y) {

        var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y)
        $("#directionsPanel").html("");
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var request = {
            origin: origin,
            destination: $('.lat').text() + ',' + $('.lng').text() ,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
            provideRouteAlternatives: true,
            region: "GB"
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {

                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                $(".noValidRoute").hide();

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a "radius" variable you can pass on. not sure how to do in JS, but with the web-api look at this:

http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=xml&ll=43.19199,-5.4288&radius=500

it returns nothing

change radius to 5000 and you get a result. if that doesnt work, try a higher zoom level?